# ASP.NET Core MVC redirect all subdirectory and files in specific folder with route in controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project, and I need to set up a redirect routing for all files and subfolder into a specific folder.

This work great for urls like `/images/foo.png` but not for `/images/sub1/foo.png` nor for `/images/sub1/sub2/foo.png`.

```
[Route("/images/{restOfPath}")]
```

I need a route to capture everything in the `images` folder.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "catch-all" parameter `**` to implement this. Here is a sample.

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public SampleController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}

[HttpGet("/Images/{**restOfPath}")]
public IActionResult Index(string restOfPath)
{
    var imagesRoot = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "images", restOfPath);
    var contentType = "image/png";

    return PhysicalFile(imagesRoot, contentType);
}
```

[image]
[image]